# Speeding up Google contact fetch

Tags: android, database, performance

I am fetching address(city, country, street, phone, email, website, organization, and so on). When I fetch all these values, it takes long time to be fetched.

This is working fine, but takes long time to be fetched.

How can this be improved?

```
public void Get_Contact_Address(String id) {
    String[] pro = new String[] {
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CITY,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.TYPE,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.STREET,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.POSTCODE };

    String where = ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + " = ? AND "
            + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " = ?";
    String[] whereParams = new String[] {
            id,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE };
    Cursor addrCur = contentresolver.query(
            ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, pro, where, whereParams,
            null);

    while (addrCur.moveToNext()) {
        String type = Null_check(addrCur
                .getString(addrCur
                        .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.TYPE)));
        if (type.equals("2")) {
            contactcontent.contact_work_address_city = Null_check(addrCur
                    .getString(addrCur
                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CITY)));
            contactcontent.contact_work_address_postcode = Null_check(addrCur
                    .getString(addrCur
                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.POSTCODE)));
            contactcontent.contact_work_address_street = Null_check(addrCur
                    .getString(addrCur
                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.STREET)));
            break;
        }
    }
    addrCur.close();

}
```

Comment: What is source of your fetching?